# Trying to select Marketplace AMI with AWS Educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just started with AWS system by educational account. I am trying to set up AMI, OpenVPN in particular, but get this error. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an explicit deny for your user which is the result of being in an AWS Educate account.

Whilst you can use the EC2 service, AWS Educate specifically states the following:

> No Marketplace EC2 supported

For a full list of supported services take a look at the [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf) pdf.

If you want an OpenVPN instance you would need to either install the dependencies on a standard EC2 image, or launch in a standard AWS account.